# Imagick resizeImage(): What argument to use when not specifying maximum height in imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, resize-image

I'm using imagick 3.7.0 compiled against ImageMagick 7.0.10-23 Q16 x86_64

In previous versions of imagick, I could resize an image with the width specified but the height unlimited using this command, where $width is a specific size but null is intended to mean unlimited for the height:

`resizeImage($width, null, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);`

With the new imagick I've loaded to use PHP 8.1, the null is throwing an error on my server:

> Imagick::resizeImage(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($rows) of type int is deprecated

What is the proper argument to supply to the second parameter in this case?

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe try `-1` and see?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That does seem to work. I'm curious if that's the best practice, though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It was a guess.

Answer (score 0):

if you pass `$bestFit=true`, the image keeps the scale. `$width` and `$height` are treated as max-with and max-height. So if you pass a very large `$height`, the image-size will be limited be the provided `$width`. For example:

```
resizeImage($width, 999999, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, true);
```

See: http://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/resizeImage?width=200&height=500&blur=1&filter_type=Lanczos&crop=Disabled&best_fit=Enabled&image_path=Lorikeet